# public static methods in class with only package visiblility?

Tags: java

Is there a problem if I make all `static` methods `public` in a class with only package visibility?  I do *not* want the methods to be accessible outside the package unless I change the class visibility to be public, in which case I *do* want them all to be visible without having to individually make them public.

Will making all `static` methods `public` while not making the class `public` satisfy the requirements above?

**Update/Clarification:** As a clarification, the `static` methods are factory methods so I want them available to anybody who can see the class. That's why I want to keep them at maximal visibility (instead of minimal visibility as commonly suggested) so that they are visible to whoever can see the class. And when the class visibility expands I do not have to hunt and find the static methods to change their visibility too. I want a single flip switch.

Comment: Yes it will, why not simply try it ?

Comment: Isn't this rather bad style - using `public` and relying on other mechanisms to get it protected? It's definitely bad for readability.

Comment: @gexicide it works when I try it; I just didn't want there to be any gotchas.

Comment: @blafasel As a clarification, the `static` methods are factory methods so I want them available to anybody who can see the class. That's why I want to keep them at maximal visibility (instead of minimal visibility as commonly suggested) so that they are visible to whoever can see the class. And when the class visibility expands I do not have to hunt and find the static methods to change their visibility too. I want a single flip switch.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is a normal use case for access modifiers. There is nothing wrong with having public methods in a class with package visibility.

However, 'all' static methods need not be kept public. You should still use private and protected methods for tasks which are internal/implementation specific.

The idea is to keep the accessibility as minimal as possible at first, and then expose them when required. By 'Accessability to minimum' i mean only the combined effect. As long as the effect is same it doesn't matter how it is achieved. The only other consideration is rework... when you eventually make this class public, do you want these methods to be visible? If yes, you better keep the methods public.

Note that for static methods 'effect is the same'. However for instance methods, a subclass would be able to provide access to the public method in a package-level class. So in that case the effect would not be the same.

Comment: +1 thanks for confirming my intuition. However, your last sentence/paragraph seems to create some doubt again because it makes me think that perhaps I should keep the `static` methods package and ONLY make them `public` when I make the class `public` (so several changes just to expose it). On the other hand your first paragraph seems to encourage keeping them `public` and simply make the class  with package visibility to hide them.

Comment: As a clarification, the `static` methods are factory methods so I want them available to anybody who can see the class. That's why I want to keep them at maximal visibility (instead of minimal visibility as your last para says) so that they are visible to whoever can see the class.

Comment: By 'Accessability to minimum' i meant only the combined effect. As long as the effect is same it doesn't matter how it is achieved. The only other consideration is rework... when you eventually make this class public, do you want these methods to be visible? If yes, you better keep the methods public.

Comment: Thanks! If you could clarify it a little bit I will accept your answer (just edit the answer in light of my edit of the question where I added the "Update/Clarification:").

Answer (score 1):

In general as a design principle, access modifiers of any method or instance variable should have same or narrow visibility (access modifier).